# Can't find source path /home/username/.cache/flatpak-monitor: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions

When i run
`flatpak run --branch=stable org.pitivi.Pitivi`,
i get the error:

`Can't create file at /home/mihail/.var/app/org.pitivi.Pitivi/config/user-dirs.dirs: Permission denied`

When i type sudo before the command.

`Can't find source path /home/mihail/.cache/flatpak-monitor: Permission denied`

Comment: can you add the output of the following commands? `ls -l /home/mihail/.var/app/org.pitivi.Pitivi/config/` and `ls -latr /home/mihail/`

Delete the entries you might don't want to share.

Comment: `total 0` is output of `ls -l /home/mihail/.var/app/org.pitivi.Pitivi/config/`

Comment: This: http://pastebin.com/MuLeuCKr is the output of the `ls -latr /home/mihail/`

Answer (score 0):

From your output I've to highlight the following:

1. This directory is owned by `root`, that's why the first command give permissions errors

**-rwxr-xr-x**  1 root   root      23052 Dec 29 21:36 pitivi-flatpak

2. The following directory doesn't allow "others" than the owner to make modifications

**drwx------** 24 mihail mihail     4096 Dec 29 21:34 .cache

How to solve?, run:

```
sudo chown -R mihail:mihail /home/mihail/pitivi-flatpak
flatpak run --branch=stable org.pitivi.Pitivi
```

This should help you to avoid current issues. If this works, I can extend myself in the explanation of why this happened and why this commands helped.

Comment: chown: cannot access '/home/mihail/pitivi-flatpak': No such file or directory

Comment: I solved the error by doing `sudo chown -R mihail:mihail /home/mihail/.var`

Comment: That path wasn't in your original question, this may happened 'cause a mixed installation with root-permissions and with regular user permissions. I guess my answer point you in the right direction, isn't it?